# Find four related words in a word search

Tags: word, wordplay, word-search

This puzzle was given to me by a friend, who had received it from his professor.

This puzzle contains a word search with 4 hidden words. Your task is to identify these 4 words. The solution to the puzzle will be the "common adjective" shared by all four words.

I've noticed the word "EGGSHELL" located in the second row in reverse order. Could you assist in locating the remaining three words?

Here is the text version of this puzzle:

```
QRNQHJMOESF
OPCLLEHSGGE
ZAOKOKKVENQ
MRLSSALGIIV
LVABCGZECAE
WYTFBYRQQLJ
JBSFFLMZQEH
BLYAZQWFYCF
YQRJDAGHDRO
ERCJGGVQQOS
SUMBTRWOCPA
```

There is also another clue he gave which is "Red Pill" (linked to the Misogynist ideology). However, he and I am not sure whether this is related to this puzzle or not.

[image: Word Search Puzzle]

Comment: Per [a question you deleted](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/125758/find-the-riddle-word-not-so-easy) (after the framing was pointed out as suspect), I'm suspicious that this is actually from some sort of competition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is

> **FRAGILE**

> [image]

> You can see crystal, glass, eggshell, porcelain highlighted in red and all these words have this adjective in common.